# Delphi: How to hide ancestor constructors?

Tags: delphi, constructor, delphi-5, constructor-chaining

> **Update:** gutted the question with a simpler example, that isn't answered
>   by the originally accepted answer

Given the following class, and its ancestor:

```
TComputer = class(TObject)
public
   constructor Create(Teapot: string='');
end;

TCellPhone = class(TComputer)
public
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer); overload; virtual;
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer; Teapot: string); overload; virtual;
end;
```

Right now `TCellPhone` has 3 constructors visible:

- Cup: Integer
- Cup: Integer; Teapot: string
- Teapot: string = ''

What do i do to `TCellPhone` so that the ancestor constructor (`Teapot: string = ''`) is not visible, leaving only the declared constructors:

- Cup: Integer
- Cup: Integer; Teapot: string

> **Note**: Usually the simple act of *having* a descendant constructor hides the ancestor:
>
> ```
> TCellPhone = class(TComputer)
> public
>    constructor Create(Cup: Integer); virtual;
> end;
> ```
>
> - Cup: Integer
>
> And if you **wanted** to keep both the
>   ancestor constructor and the
>   descendant, you would mark the
>   descendant as an `overload`:
>
> ```
> TCellPhone = class(TComputer)
> public
>    constructor Create(Cup: Integer); overload; virtual;
> end;
> ```
>
> - Cup: Integer
> - Teapot: string = ''

In this question's example code, Delphi is mistaking my `overload` keywords:

```
TCellPhone = class(TComputer)
public
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer); overload; virtual;
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer; Teapot: string); overload; virtual;
end;
```

to think that:

- i want to overload my constructors with the **ancestor**,
- when really i want to overload it with the **sibling**

How do i hide the ancestor constructor?

**Note:** It might be impossible to hide the ancestor, non-virtual, constructor using the Delphi language as it is currently defined. ***"Not possible"*** is a valid answer.

---

### Attempted Answer (failed)

i **tried** marking the descendant constructors with `reintroduce` (falling back to my mode of randomly adding keywords until it works):

```
TCellPhone = class(TComputer)
public
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer); reintroduce; overload; virtual;
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer; Teapot: string); reintroduce; overload; virtual;
end;
```

But that didn't work, all three constructors are still visible. :(

---

### Original Question

i have an object that descends from a class that has constructors don't want to see:

```
TEniac = class(TObject)
   constructor Create(PowerCord: TPowerCord=nil); //calls inherited Create

TComputer = class(TEniac) ...
   constructor Create(PowerCord: TPowerCord=nil); //calls inherited Create(nil)

TCellPhone = class(TComputer)
   constructor Create(sim: TSimChip; UnlockCode: Integer); //calls inherited Create(nil)

TiPhone = class(TCellPhone)
   constructor Create(sim: TSimChip); //calls inherited Create(sim, 0)
```

> **Note:** This is a hypothetical example. As in the real world, the ancestor objects cannot be changed without breaking existing code.

Now when someone's using `TiPhone` i don't want them even being able to *see* the constructor from `TEniac`:

```
iphone := TiPhone.Create(powerCord);
```

Worse still: if they call that constructor, they completely miss my constructor, and everything done in between. It's pretty easy to call the wrong constructor, all of them are visible in the IDE code-completion, and will compile:

```
TiPhone.Create;
```

and they get a completely invalid object.

i could change `TCellPhone` to throw an exception in those constructors:

```
TCellPhone.Create(PowerCord: TPowercord)
begin
   raise Exception.Create('Don''t use.');
end;
```

But developers won't realize they're calling the wrong constructor until the customer finds the error one day and fines us bazillions of dollars. In fact, i'm ***trying*** to find everywhere i call the wrong constructor - but i can't figure out how to make Delphi tell me!

Comment: *"hypothetical example"* i'm afraid you're going to have to follow the concepts along in your brain, rather than in an IDE.

Comment: I guess this question is *too* hypothetical for me, then. :-)

Comment: @Ulrich Gerhardt i could write the dozens of lines of code to come up with a compilable example - but that misses the point of readable code in the question. Questions 4 or 5 pages long and people simply stop reading; or worse: skim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's impossible to ever make a constructors introduced in an ancestor inaccessible for the creation of a derived class in Delphi because you can always do this:

```
type
  TComputerClass = class of TComputer;

var
  CellPhoneClass: TComputerClass = TCellPhone;
  CellPhone : TCellPhone;
begin
  CellPhone := CellPhoneClass.Create('FUBAR') as TCellPhone;
end;
```

Nothing you could do in the code of any derived class would ever be able to prevent anyone from calling the TComputer.Create constructor for creating an instance of the derived class.

The best you could do is:

```
TComputer = class(TObject)
public
   constructor Create(Teapot: string=''); virtual;
end;

TCellPhone = class(TComputer)
public
   constructor Create(Teapot: string=''); overload; override;
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer); overload; virtual;
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer; Teapot: string); overload; virtual;
end;
```

In that case the code above would at least be calling `TCellPhone.Create(Teapot: string='')` instead of `TComputer.Create(Teapot: string='')`

Answer (score 8):

If I remember correctly, then [`reintroduce`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Reintroduce) should help for **virtual** methods.

> The **reintroduce** directive suppresses compiler warnings about hiding previously declared virtual methods.
>   Use reintroduce when you want to hide an inherited virtual method with a new one.

To answer your updated question - I think it's not possbile to hide a **non-virtual** constructor with overloading in a directly derived class, but I tried the following successfully:

```
TComputer = class(TObject)
public
  constructor Create(Teapot: string='');
end;

TIndermediateComputer = class(TComputer)
protected
  // hide the constructor
  constructor Create;
end;

TCellPhone = class(TIndermediateComputer)
public
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer); overload; virtual;
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer; Teapot: string); overload; virtual;
end;
```

Comment: Reintroduce may suppress the compiler warnings about hiding an ancestor method, but how does it help in identifying the use of the constructors that shouldn't be used at **compile** time? Instead of just throwing an exception at **run** time, when the customers may sue poor Ian for all he's got?

Comment: @Marjan Venema In this case `reintroduce` isn't being used for it's documented purpose; there *are* no warnings about hiding ancestor methods (it turns out that you don't see that warning if the ancestor methods are not virtual). In this case i can use `reintroduce` for it's secret ability to hide ancestor methods.

Comment: @Ian. Oh, dear, brain went to idle it seems. Ok, so no compile time messages, but when re-implementing the constructors you can either throw an exception or call the correct constructor with a default parameter...

Answer (score 5):

Instead of only raising an "Don't use" exception in the overridden invalid constructors, consider marking them **deprecated** in the class where they become invalid. That should produce nice compiler warnings when these invalid constructors are used erroneosly.

```
TCellPhone = class(TComputer)
   constructor Create(PowerCord: TPowerCord=nil); deprecated;
   constructor Create(sim: TSimChip; UnlockCode: Integer); //calls inherited Create(nil)
```

In addition, use override or reintroduce as needed.

Comment: i would **love** to go back in time and add `deprecated` keyword to Delphi **5**. i'll add that to my list, right after telling Copernicus that the planets follow and elliptical orbit.

Comment: Imagine how much more advanced humanity could be if i could go back in time and give people the right ideas at the right time.

Comment: @Ian: ah yes, but then again: wouldn't that take much of the fun out of the journey of discovery? :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can't hide the parent class' constructor unless it was declared virtual or dynamic. You can however prevent it from being called from the child class. Consider your example:

```
TComputer = class(TObject)
public
   constructor Create(Teapot: string='');
end;

TCellPhone = class(TComputer)
public
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer); overload; virtual;
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer; Teapot: string); overload; virtual;
end;
```

`TComputer.Create` will always be visible from `TCellPhone`. You can prevent `TComputer.Create` from being inadvertantly called by declaring a `TCellPhone.Create` with the same signature.

```
TCellPhone = class(TComputer)
public
   constructor Create(Teapot: string='');
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer); overload; virtual;
   constructor Create(Cup: Integer; Teapot: string); overload; virtual;
end;
```

Then as long as you don't have a call to `inherited` in the body of `TCellPhone.Create(Teapot: string='')` you can prevent `TComputer.Create` from being called in `TCellPhone` and its descendants. The following:

```
TCellphone.Create;
TCellphone.Create('MyPhone');
```

Will resolve to TCellPhone's implementation.

Additionally:

```
TiPhone = class(TCellPhone)
    constructor Create;
end;

constructor TiPhone.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;
```

Will invoke `TCellPhone.Create` and not `TComputer.Create`.

Comment: *"You can't hide the parent class' constructor unless it was declared virtual or dynamic."* This isn't strictly true. You **can** hide the parent class's constructor, even though it is not virtual/dynamic, simply by declaring a new constructor.

Comment: @Ian but as you found out when you overloaded the constructor in the child class the parent class' constructor became visible again. Using my suggestion will effectively block the parent constructor from being called from the child.

Answer (score 1):

You want to reintroduce the constructor:

```
TiPhone = class(TCellPhone)
    constructor Create(sim: TSimChip); reintroduce;
```

See `TComponent.Create` in the Delphi source code for a real-world example of this.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is 5 years old topic, but still it may help someone.
The only way to hide the ancestor's constructor is to rename one of the two Create methods to something else and remove the need of *overload* directive.
It looks weird but it's the only way. At least in older versions of Delphi. I don't know is it possible now in the XE xxx versions.